# Проблема при установке виджета Контур.Отель на Eementor

Tags: виджет, elementor, интеграция

При просмотре на секунду появляется в нужном месте и исчезает. Вставляю в виджет html.

[Страница сайта с проблемой](https://xn--21-6kcaak5cel6g.xn--p1ai/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/)